# How to call feild name in postman request body defined in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, postman

I have declared two enums in two separate application.properties file and I have also created a class for constant values.

Application.properties file1

```
EnumProperty.Provider=Provider1
url1=http://localhost:8080/some/url
```

Application.properties file2

```
EnumProperties.Provider=Provider2
url1=http://localhost:8080/some/urlss
```

CommonConstant.class

```
public final String PROVIDER1 = "PROVIDER1";
public final String PROVIDER2="PROVIDER2";
```

Also I have ConfigurationReader.class

```
@Value("{EnumProperty.Provider}")
private String providerOne;

@Value("{EnumProperties.Provider}")
private String providerTwo;
```

Now I have a service class where I'm suppose to call one class out of two based on which provider I'm calling.Which is as follows

```
public ResponseObject service(CommonRequestFeilds commonRequestFeilds) {

        if (configurationReader.getProviderOne().equals(CommonConstant.PROVIDER1)) {
            classOneServiceImp.someMethodOfClass1(commonRequestFeilds);
        }

        else if (configurationReader.getProviderTwo().equals(CommonConstant.PROVIDER2)) {
            classTwoServiceImp.someMethodOfClass2(commonRequestFeilds);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Also CommonRequestFeild.class

```
private String email;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;
```

Postman RequestBody

```
{ 
   "email":"john@example.com",
   "firstName":"John",
   "lastName":"Doe",
}
```

Now in postman request body I'm sending the commonRequestFeilds values.But where I'm stuck is how do I tell in my postman request body which provider I'm trying to call from ConfigurationReader class.Should I declare ConfigurationReader class in CommonRequestFeild class? Please help.